# Dsx-desktop error - "Install.js: Unable to login to the registry."

Tags: windows, data-science-experience, dsx-desktop

I'm working through problems with the DSX Desktop installation on Windows 7. Most installation attempts failed when the progress bar for "Checking Docker Status" hung at 10%, and after a few minutes the installation aborted silently without any message or errors.

After restarting Docker the DSX Desktop installation went a bit further, but then aborted with this error log:

```
Error Log
Install.js: Unable to login to the registry.
[2017-04-14 04:22:59:0334] [info] function login()
[2017-04-14 04:23:45:0199] [info] Listing VMS: "ibm-dsx" {45b425be-d685-4da0-ae3f-dfc5b3d29562}
[2017-04-14 04:23:57:0017] [info] runCommand: docker login --username=token --password=Xxxx na.cumulusrepo.com
[2017-04-14 04:23:57:0018] [error] exec error: Error: Command failed: (@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd ibm-dsx') DO @%i) && docker login --username=token --password=Xxxx na.cumulusrepo.com
Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running
[2017-04-14 04:23:57:0018] [error] stderr: Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running
[2017-04-14 04:23:57:0018] [info] Resetting VM: Error: Unable to turn off docker-machine
[2017-04-14 04:23:57:0018] [info] Logging in using toolbox: false
[2017-04-14 04:23:57:0047] [error] Install.js: Unable to login to the registry.
[2017-04-14 04:23:57:0048] [info] cancelClicked state: false
```

I have seen this other [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569624/docker-for-windows-open-cmd-executing-docker-machine-env) but that is not for dsx desktop.

---

**Update**

I have just seen the following note:

> If you opted not to install the Docker in the default path, append your Docker directory path to your PATH environment variable to prevent a registry logging error (you might need to temporarily disable your firewall if the problem persists).

I'll try this when I'm back at my machine and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to open virtualbox and manually start the ibm-dsx instance.  After starting, the installation finished successfully.